# Custom JSON field names with Newtonsoft as defined by a variable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but here goes:

I want to specify dynamic field names for the Newtonsoft.JSON serializer.

Example:
For the sake of demonstration purposes, say a basic login system with user details stored in JSON files. Authentication details would be stored in this manner:

```
{
    "username": "password"
}
```

How would I specify what to put in the field name before I serialize the JSON?

Comment: Oh, that's about serialization?

Comment: @Cid Yes, I'm trying to serialize JSON. Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @Jimi That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do